# What is the time complexity of bitwise operations in python?

Tags: python, integer, time-complexity, bitwise-operators, built-in-types

Usually we consider bitwise operations to have *O*(1) worst-case time complexity because of built-in hardware support in most platforms. Since python `int`s can represent numbers in an unlimited range, which do not in general fit into a CPU-word, I would like to know what are the worst-case time complexities of the different bitwise operations on `int`s in general, and also specifically for `int`s that actually do fit in a cpu-word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really give all the ingredients for the answer.

Quoting from [a blog by Victor Skvortsov](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-8-how-python-integers-work/):

> Everything related to the representation of Python integers can be found in [`Include/longintrepr.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Include/longintrepr.h). Technically, Python integers are instances of `PyLongObject`, which is defined in [`Include/longobject.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Include/longobject.h), but PyLongObject is actually a typedef for `struct _longobject` that is defined in `Include/longintrepr.h`:
>
> ```
> struct _longobject {
>     PyVarObject ob_base; // expansion of PyObject_VAR_HEAD macro
>     digit ob_digit[1];
> };
> ```
>
> This struct extends [`PyVarObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject), which in turn extends [`PyObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject):
>
> ```
> typedef struct {
>     PyObject ob_base;
>     Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
> } PyVarObject;
> ```
>
> So, besides a reference count and a type that all Python objects have,
> an integer object has two other members:
>
> - `ob_size` that comes from `PyVarObject`; and
> - `ob_digit` that is defined in `struct _longobject`.
>
> The `ob_digit` member is a pointer to an array of digits. On 64-bit platforms, each digit is a 30-bit integer that takes values between 0 and 2^30-1 and is stored as an unsigned 32-bit int (`digit` is a typedef for `uint32_t`). On 32-bit platforms, each digit is a 15-bit integer that takes values between 0 and 2^15-1 and is stored as an unsigned 16-bit int (`digit` is a typedef for `unsigned short`).

This confirms what you wrote, i.e. that Python integers are represented as an array of fixed sized words.

So bit operations will have a time complexity that is *O(k)* where *k* is the total size of such array(s). Or, if we want to express this in terms of the *value* *n* of the integer involved, it is *O(logn)*.